# How do I set up file watcher in PhpStorm for Harp.js command line command "harp compile"?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to set up my file watcher so that it automatically runs `harp compile` in the command line when I make changes to a file or save. How do I set that up on this screen?

[image]

Comment: So if `harp compile` is the actual command to run then: 1) Program -- path top the `harp` executable; 2) Arguments -- `compile`; 3) May want to change the Working Directory to be the project root *I guess* (since I have no idea what `harp compile` does and what files it works with/generates; 4) You want to disable "Auto-save edited files" option otherwise IDE will try to run this file watcher ~1 sec after you change the file (will not wait for you doing a Save first so you can easily end up with the broken code/compilation error).

Comment: 5) Fine tune Files to Watch (otherwise IDE can trigger this file watcher for unrelated files). 6) You may want to configure "Output paths to refresh" as well -- but I have no idea what to put here. This is where you tell -- check these files/folders for changes after file watcher finishes running 9so IDE is aware of the changes made outside) **P.S.** Just keep in mind: File Watcher is just a command that IDE runs for you instead of you going into terminal and executing it there.